# How to exclude the product of category

Tags: magento, product

I am displaying all the products from the subcategories of the parent category. I want to exclude the product of the specific subcategory from that parent category product listing page. ex. I have parent category as fruits and its subcategories as mango banana orange i want to display only mango and banana products on the fruits category page not orange products

Comment: Here the subcategories are displayed with levels. you can display upto which level you want. These levels are like level 0, level 1, level2 etc...

Comment: You are not getting my questions i want to exclude the products of the specific category.

Comment: I think this helps for u http://amirshakya.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/magento-exclude-categories-from-top-category-menu-navigation/

Comment: Thanxxx I tried that but not get what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in 2 ways. First one, You can simply un select the product which are not to be displayed in the Fruits page through Manage Product->[required product]->Categories.Here select the Mango and unselect Orange.

And the next one, You can get the Product Collection and through `Mage::getModel(catalog/category)` you can get the IDs Of all the top categories and child Categories. Asusal the product which is not to be displayed contains the top category ID and its own ID. Here you can give the ID as statically and remove them.

Comment: Cheers..
which method did you followed, 1st method or second one??

Comment: @chirag Cheers.. Happy to know that it helped you. Upvote the answer. Then it may be helpful for others also..

Comment: I accepted the answer i dont have reputation to upvote sry :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add restrictions by category id. Check your category ids and add one if.

Comment: I want to add loop in the list.phtml file where all the product collection is come so how can i add restriction an u please tell me.   Thanxxx

Answer (score 0):

```
     $arrayOfCatToBeExc = array(1,3,4); 
     // for example id of your categories  and write one if to check  
     if(in_array($_product->getCategory(),$arrayOfCatToBeExc){
     continue;
     }
```

Comment: i try that but not getting any luck

Comment: Did you receive category id from product?

Comment: Yes i got category id of parent